# How to add legend in a plot with stacked bars and a lina

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add the legend of all the variables plotted in the graph (and no title for the legend). However I do not manage to get the legend of the line right.

```
library(ggplot2)

mydatastack <- my_data_sub2[-(1:4), -(2:8)]
mydatastack2 <- mydatastack %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Growth_")), ~ gsub("Growth_", "", .))
mydatastack2 <- melt(mydatastack2, id.vars = c("Date"),
              measure.vars = c("Index", "Compensation", "Profits", "Interest", "Depreciation", "Corpotaxes", "Taxes"))

# Filter out Growth_Index for the bar plot
bar_data <- subset(mydatastack2, variable != "Index")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = bar_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable), stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(data = subset(mydatastack2, variable == "Index"), aes(x = Date, y = value), color = "blue", show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()
```

My result:

my result after the change:
[image]

Comment: As you won't get a legend for your "line". If you want a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e move `color="...` inside aes(), e.g. do `aes(..., color = "blue")` in `geom_line`  then set your color using `scale_color_manual(values = "blue")`. For more help please you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared using `dput()`.

Comment: Thank you! It does work. But how can I remove the title of the legend which now is as colour.

Comment: Do `+ labs(color = NULL)` to remove the legend title for the color legend.

Comment: So in this case it can't say anything else than "blue"?

Comment: You can set the text to be displayed in the legend using `scale_color_manual(..., labels = "My Fancy Line")`. And in general I would recommend to use a better placeholder than `"blue"` in aes(), perhaps `aes(color = "line")`.